# Django Rest Framework: Adding a custom field to a paginated ViewSet

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a paginated result set so the response comes back like this:

```
{
"count": 944,
"next": "http://api.visitorlando.teeny/consumer/listings/?page=3",
"previous": "http://api.visitorlando.teeny/consumer/listings/",
"results": [
 {...}]
}
```

I need to add another custom field to the Response like this:

```
{
"count": 944,
"custom_field": "test",
"next": "http://api.visitorlando.teeny/consumer/listings/?page=3",
"previous": "http://api.visitorlando.teeny/consumer/listings/",
"results": [
 {...}]
}
```

and I am inside a ViewSet. How am I able to do this?

Comment: you can find solution here. http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#custom-pagination-styles

Answer (score 11):

You may define your custom paginate class:

```
class CustomPagination(pagination.PageNumberPagination):
    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        return Response({
            'links': {
               'next': self.get_next_link(),
               'previous': self.get_previous_link()
            },
            'count': self.page.paginator.count,
            'results': data,
            "custom_field": "test",
        })


class YourListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    pagination_class = CustomPagination
```

more details: [custom-pagination](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#custom-pagination-styles)

Comment: Not sure why I didn't see in the DRF docs the first time. Appreciate your time.